# Woocommerce Category Hook

Tags: woocommerce, hook

My main shop page is pulling in categories. Each category shows the category title and image.

I am trying to insert a Read more button to appear underneath each product category that will then go through to the category page.

I cannot find a hook for this to go into functions.php

Answer (score 1):

`woocommerce_after_subcategory_title` would be a viable option. You can see it in the [`content-product_cat.php`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/content-product_cat.php#L63) template.

Comment: Thanks! Here is the full code I used for anyone else who is interested: 
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_subcategory_title', 'cat_button', 5 );
function cat_button() {
 echo ' <div class="button2">Read more</div>'; 
}